# Memory Leak occurring When Inserting 1000 Text Files buffers into std::map

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stdmap

I am encountering a memory leak issue in my sample code.

I have continuously inserted 1000 text file buffers into a `std::map` with a 4 second interval. The total size of the 1000 files is around 116 MB. Initially, the application's memory size is 2 MB.

After some iterations (around the 50th iteration), the memory size increases by around 50 MB and is not being released. It always
maintains around 50 to 60 MB.

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> data_map_;

std::mutex c_mutex;

std::string readFile(const std::string &filename)
{
    if (boost::filesystem::exists(filename))
    {
        std::ifstream in(filename, std::ios::binary);
        const auto beg = in.tellg();
        in.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
        const auto end = in.tellg();
        const auto sz = end - beg;
        std::string buffer;
        if (0 != sz)
        {
            in.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
            buffer.resize(sz);
            in.read(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
        }
        return buffer;
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}

void load_file(std::string &fname, data_map_ &img_data_map)
{
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(c_mutex);
        img_data_map.insert(std::make_pair(fname, readFile(fname)));
    }
}

void preparelist(std::vector<fs::path> &pathList, data_map_ &txt_map)
{
    for (auto filePath : pathList)
    {
        std::string f_path = filePath.string();
        load_file(f_path, (txt_map));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string dir_path = "F:/tmp/1000_files"; // Folder size 116 MB
    std::vector<fs::path> pathList;
    std::copy(fs::recursive_directory_iterator(dir_path), fs::recursive_directory_iterator(), back_inserter(pathList));
    int i = 1;

    while (true)
    {
        {
            data_map_ txt_map;
            preparelist(pathList, std::ref(txt_map));
            txt_map.clear();
        }// txt_map scope will clear.
        std::cout << "Images are Prepared : " << i << std::endl;
        i++;
        boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(4));
    }
}
```

Why is the memory not being cleared?

How to clear the memory?

Comment: Note that "not giving memory back to the OS" is not the same as "there exists a memory leak".

Comment: That does not sound like a memory leak. Expecting memory to be released back to the operating system (O/S) is a common misunderstanding of how the C++ heap works (in practise). If you really want memory to be released to the O/S you will have to do a lot more work and use low level O/S calls that do guarantee that memory is released to the O/S

Comment: Well you keep on reading the files and store their contents in the map, remove and then read into the map again. If the memory was released back to the OS then the OS would have to map memory pages, unmap memory pages, and map pages again a lot of times. That's a waste of time, wouldn't you say? Keeping those pages mapped to the process would save a lot of time.

Comment: Why are you doing this? When are you going to stop reading large files into memory and *do some work* that enables you to release the memory? What is the underlying problem here?

Comment: What's the purpose of `c_mutex` and the `reference_wrapper` in `preparelist(pathList, std::ref(txt_map));` in this example code?

Comment: As you're not using `new` or `malloc` or `std::shared_ptr` it's pretty difficult to get a memory leak. You might be storing objects you don't need, but they've not been leaked, they just need removing from the map

Comment: 1) This does not sound like a memory leak since there's no memory allocated that you've lost track of and cannot free. 2) Just because you `delete` or `free` some memory on the heap doesn't mean it's released back to the OS - it's usually cached for reuse (which is a good thing). 3) Since you are (probably) on a system employing virtual memory, it hardly matters - each process gets its own virtual memory space and allocations are usually not fulfilled anyway until the program actually writes to the mem and, the kernel can swap out unused (or rarely used) pages of another program if needed.